# How to solve module problem in Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I have a code as below.

I run this code using `python 3.7` idle, which runs successfully. But when I save it as `file.py` and run it from using cmd, it pops `import module` error.

My code:

```
import requests 
from lxml import html
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
# url to scrape data from 
link = 'https://www.bhaskar.com/sports/'

# path to particular element 
path = '//*[@id="top-nav1"]'

response = requests.get(link,headers) 
byte_string = response.content 

# get filtered source code 
source_code = html.fromstring(byte_string) 
print(source_code)
# jump to preferred html element 
tree = source_code.xpath(path) 
print(tree.text_content())
```

> Error : cannot import name 'html' from 'lxml'

I can not understand when both are running on the same python files why such Error pop!!!
[image: In this image you can see no error thrown]

[image: i saved code as lxml.py, throws error while executing]

Comment: Are you using virtual environments?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the error

Comment: no, i am not using virtual environment, i have mentioned both images ,might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing Python's import machinery by having named your script `lxml.py`, the same name as the `lxml` package you're importing.

Rename it to, say `lxml_test_thing.py` and it'll work.